# Google Play Store Beta review have a effect to Production review?

Tags: android, review

1. app bundle(ex. 7(0.1.0)) have been approved beta test track.
2. and we were submit production track used the bundle.
3. after 10 minute, The Production track have been approved production track.

so I Think reviewed bundle is automately apporve.
Is it true?

I tried search in google. but, I don't find relevant info.